# nodemailer maximum number of tries

Tags: node.js, nodemailer

I am trying email from nodemailer. Is there any option that maximum number of retries can be limited if a email(to the person it is sent) is not working. The problem arises when gmail is used and the retries fills the quota limit.

Comment: I'll not make this an answer because it's very opinionated, but even the very short github-repo read me says: ` If Gmail does not work for you then don't use it.`. So, may I suggest [mailgun](https://mailgun.com) instead. And while you are at it, drop nodemailer for [mailgun-js](https://github.com/bojand/mailgun-js). :P (Sorry!)

Comment: Mailgun-js seems to have validate option and also max retries.Looking into it.
also looking at the mailgun and trying to add in my domain.
Thanks.